# get a listbox binding on both the calendar and a combobox VIDEO

Tags: sql, sql-server, wpf, database, visual-studio-2010

I have filmed my problem as it is easier to explain on video. I want the listbox to display the time began from the bookings table, that relies on the date from the bookings table and the room from the rooms table, is that possible.

**Here is a link to the video: [Video of Problem](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FX22thFJF5g)**

Here is the generated XAML:

```
   <CollectionViewSource x:Key="bookingsViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:Booking}, CreateList=True}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="roomsViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:Room}, CreateList=True}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="roomsBookingsViewSource" Source="{Binding Bookings, Source={StaticResource roomsViewSource}}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="bookingsBookingsViewSource" Source="{Binding Bookings, Source={StaticResource bookingsViewSource}}"/>
```

This is for the grid:

```
  <Grid x:Name="Grid" SizeChanged="Grid_SizeChanged" Margin="0,0,-0.4,-0.2" DataContext="{StaticResource bookingsViewSource}"     >
```

This is for the calendar:

```
<Calendar x:Name="MainCalendar" Margin="10,135.2,231.8,0" Grid.Row="2" ToolTip="Select a date"
DisplayDateStart="2013-01-01" DisplayDateEnd="2020-01-01" FirstDayOfWeek="Monday" Height="177" 
VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" SelectedDatesChanged="datechanged" 
DisplayDate="{Binding SelectedDate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" SelectedDate="
{Binding Date, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"   >
```

This is for the combobox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="roomnameComboBox" Grid.Column="1" DisplayMemberPath="Room.Roomname" 
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="3,5,0,0" Grid.Row="0" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120">
```

And this is for the listbox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listrow" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3.2,1.2,1.8,0" Grid.Row="2" 
DisplayMemberPath="Timebegan"  SelectionChanged="listrow_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding
Source={StaticResource bookingsBookingsViewSource}}"/>
```

Here is the generated C#

```
 private void Bookings_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
        var allensCroftEntities1 = new WpfApplication7.AllensCroftEntities1();

        // Load data into Bookings. You can modify this code as needed.
        var bookingsViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("bookingsViewSource")));
        var bookingsQuery = this.GetBookingsQuery(allensCroftEntities1);
        bookingsViewSource.Source = bookingsQuery.Execute(MergeOption.AppendOnly);

        // Load data into Rooms. You can modify this code as needed.
        var roomsViewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("roomsViewSource")));
        var roomsQuery = this.GetRoomsQuery(allensCroftEntities1);
        roomsViewSource.Source = roomsQuery.Execute(MergeOption.AppendOnly);
    }


   private ObjectQuery<Booking> GetBookingsQuery(AllensCroftEntities1 allensCroftEntities1)
    {
        var bookingsQuery = allensCroftEntities1.Bookings;

        // To explicitly load data, you may need to add Include methods like below:
        // bookingsQuery = bookingsQuery.Include("Bookings.Client").
        // For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=157380
        // Update the query to include Room.Bookings data in Bookings. You can modify this code as needed.
        bookingsQuery = bookingsQuery.Include("Room.Bookings");

        // Returns an ObjectQuery.
        return bookingsQuery;
    }

     private ObjectQuery<Room> GetRoomsQuery(AllensCroftEntities1 allensCroftEntities1)
    {
        var roomsQuery = allensCroftEntities1.Rooms;

        // Update the query to include Bookings data in Rooms. You can modify this code as needed.
        roomsQuery = roomsQuery.Include("Bookings");

        // Returns an ObjectQuery.
        return roomsQuery;
    }
```

EDIT

This is what happens when i used your code, do you have an idea why? BTW, this is without the where command.
[image: booking query]

EDIT
I also tried the where suggestion, but i still get this problem in the screenshot:
[image: Where problem]

Comment: actually hamoudy didnt upvote this, i was surprised when it got upvied

Comment: I just finished watching your video. I know you probably thought a video makes it easier to understand the problem, but I think the length of it would put off people trying to help you

Comment: Thanks, i have approved your changes, but do you understand the problem?

Comment: Yes I think I've got a better understanding of your problem. But your workflow is totally different to mine and I struggled a lot. I think I know what your problem is, you say you want to "filter" your listbox results, but that is not what your query is doing. You are just using Include, which includes all related entities. I think you will need to add a Where clause to set a filter on the query

Comment: but where would i add the where clause?

Comment: I believe that would be in the BookingsLoaded method. var bookingsQuery = this.GetBookingsQuery(allensCroftEntities1) would become var bookingsQuery = this.GetBookingsQuery(allensCroftEntities1).Where(x => x.BookingsTableDateFieldName == thedatethatyouwanttofilteron);

Comment: see my latest edit as i had a bit of trouble implementing the first change to the code

Comment: I changed the code by removing the namespaces to make it more readable. Your code however does still require the namespaces to run. Normally we do this by adding a using statement right at the top of the file. There will be some default ones there already. e.g. using System; You need to add the extra ones that you need. Should be able to automatically do this by right clicking on the problem e.g. MergeOption, then a pop up menu will appear, choose Resolve and  it should prompt you with the required namespace.

Comment: Thanks, that works for the second screenshot, but i still have the same problem for the first screenshot and i did try asqueryable():      bookingsQuery = bookingsQuery.Include("Room.Bookings").AsQueryable();

Answer (score 0):

Have the Dates and the rooms bind to properties on your VM, and whenever they change, get your data from the database based on both, updating an observable collection that is bound to the third column (the one in the center of your application).

Make sure all raise the proper notifications, and you should be set.
I have a similar solution for filtering based on two combo boxes, and some text boxes depending on the above selections, and it works fine.

(and like @failedprogramming said, it is a long video ... :)